# Reflection dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.findClass() NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection

For method:

`Ldalvik/system/DexClassLoader;->findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;`

that [`DexClassLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html)
inherits from [`ClassLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)

The following call to `Class.getMethod()` fails with a `NoSuchMethodException`:

`Class.forName("dalvik.system.DexClassLoader")).getMethod("findClass",Class.forName("java.lang.String"))`

I don't understand why this call fails. Unless I am missing something, the method is inherited and should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findClass` is `protected` and will thus not be returned by `getMethod()`. Instead `getDeclaredMethod()` should be used, as it will also return `private` and `protected` access level methods.